# Как реализовать четырехуровневое меню из примера в описании?

Tags: javascript, html, css

Здравствуйте, помогите пожалуйста.
Вот пример [`меню`](https://jsfiddle.net/ufddmm67/3/), которое отлично подходит для сайта. При наведении на родительский уровень открывается дочерний, проблема в том, что при наведении на второй уровень открывается третий и четвертый сразу. Мне нужно, чтобы четвертый открывался по наведению на третий уровень.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Нужно лишь поправить селекторы, заменив `.nav > li.hover > ul , .nav li li.hover ul` на `li.hover > ul`, а `.nav li li.hover ul` на `li.hover li.hover > ul`
([результат](https://jsfiddle.net/ua53qwjh/)).

Comment: Спасибо огромное!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!

Comment: Здравствуй. Тут проблема появилась. Не подскажешь как в этом меню реализовать переход по ссылке по второму нажатию?

Answer (score 0):

1) Это `.nav li li.hover > ul {left: 100%; top: 0;}` на это: `.nav li li.hover > ul {left: 100%; top: 0;}`

2) Это `.nav > li.hover > ul , .nav li li.hover ul {position: static;}` на это: `.nav > li.hover > ul , .nav li li.hover > ul {position: static;}`

Вот пример:https://jsfiddle.net/yuri_spivak/ufddmm67/4/